# Show Visualforce page in an iframe on asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, salesforce, visualforce, apex

Can anyone tell me process of embedding Salesforce Visualforce page on ASP.NET page under an iFrame or through any other way, if you have.

Answer (score 1):

SalesForce doesn't support CORS or JSONP. This is deliberate because they want you to use their stuff:

1. Connected Apps: for communicating with "headless" applications (web services).
2. Salesforce Canvas: for embedding external applications within a VisualForce page. I am not sure if this works the other way around. Communication (events) between your SalesForce app and your external app is done via JavaScript XHR proxies. I believe this means you may have to modify your existing app to include their JavaScript library.

Both Connected Apps and Canvas apps require security setup and authentication.

I am still trying to figure this out too. The SalesForce Canvas tutorials use applications hosted on Heroku (they acquired Heroku so they push it whenever they can)... although this makes the examples close-ended, it also adds extra steps.

Answer (score 0):

check this out!

there's something called frontdoor.jsp

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/03/see-your-visualforce-pages-on-tv-with-chromecast.html